# Send fee type to Authorize.net along payment

Tags: payment-processor

I need to assign a unique code to each fee label for accounting purposes. I can do that using price sets and use the fee type to add the code. Is it possible to see the fee type information in the Authorize.net report? knowing that one transaction can have multiple fee types.
Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

By fee type I am assuming you mean financial type, but if I am not mistaken, financial type information is not transferred to any payment processor - that all remains within CiviCRM, so to get that information from a report you generate from Authorize.net would not be possible without having something developed specifically for that purpose.

If I have misunderstood and you are referring to a report that you run from within CiviCRM, it could be that you either have a custom report or renamed a built-in report - if it is the latter, please let me know the name of the report that you are using.

Hope this helps!
Tamar